# How to use subcommand with cobra golang?

Tags: go

Sorry but I cannot find a way to use the example

```
./client echo --times 10 "coucou" 
./client  --times 10 "coucou" echo
```

No way to use it... sorry for my mistake.

Best regards,
Nicolas

```
    func main() {
    var echoTimes int

    var cmdEcho = &cobra.Command{
        Use:   "echo [string to echo]",
        Short: "Echo anything to the screen",
        Long:  `echo is for echoing anything back.
        Echo works a lot like print, except it has a child command.
        `,
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            fmt.Println("Print: " + strings.Join(args, " "))
        },
    }

    var cmdTimes = &cobra.Command{
        Use:   "times [# times] [string to echo]",
        Short: "Echo anything to the screen more times",
        Long:  `echo things multiple times back to the user by providing
        a count and a string.`,
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            for i:=0; i < echoTimes; i++ {
                fmt.Println("Echo: " + strings.Join(args, " "))
            }
        },
    }

    cmdTimes.Flags().IntVarP(&echoTimes, "times", "t", 1, "times to echo the input")
    var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{Use: "app"}
    rootCmd.AddCommand(cmdEcho)
    cmdEcho.AddCommand(cmdTimes)
    rootCmd.Execute()
}
```

Comment: So, the conclusion is : No way to use it. What is the question then?

Comment: question is confusing. is that a question or statement. If statement, then it is incorrect. We can use sub commands with cobra using `.AddCommand()`

Answer (score 1):

If `times` is a command, you are not suppose to prefix it with '`--`'.

The examples you can see in [`cobra_test.go`](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/b825817fc0fc59fc1657bc8202204a04ae3d679d/cobra_test.go#L417) shows `times` uses like:

```
echo times -j 99 one two
echo times -s again -c test here
```

Answer (score 0):

for example, if your executed file named `app`, just run

```
$./app echo times -t 3 hello
 Echo: hello
 Echo: hello
 Echo: hello
```

or

```
$./app echo times --times=3 hello
Echo: hello
Echo: hello
Echo: hello
```